# This site can’t be reached on Nodejs Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm totally new to Node and I tried to run a test site on a hosting centos 7 (vultr.com). I've got nodejs, express installed.

Hello.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

run node hello.js

On my PC, http://x.x.x.x:3000/  => shows This site can’t be reached

x.x.x.x took too long to respond.

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: Where do you run it? On localhost or on a remote server?

Comment: @TzookBarNoy hello.js runs on server, and I call from my pc.

Comment: Well I'm. It sure you port is open to remote access

Comment: @AndrewLi not sure what you meant, certainly x is my server IP.  http://serverIP:3000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should consider about your server port. Have you open port 3000 in CentOS?

You can check your open port by typing

```
iptables -L
```

I think the firewall blocked your port you can open it by type this command

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: thanks, I run iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT => show nothing. I update my main post above with a snapshot of it

Comment: Yeah it is. Can you type again "iptables -L", make sure it display port 3000, then you succeeded to open your server port. You can check it again.

Comment: somehow sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT works for me. It runs now.

Comment: Great. Can you check green the answer for me?

Comment: I ran this command `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT` but figured out that I actually didn't need to. How do I reverse it such that it's as if I never ran the command?

Comment: You can reboot your system, then it will be normal state.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using remote server, probably your 8080 port is blocked.

If you have root access and port 80 is open you can try and run script with sudo

But the first option is probably your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Google Cloud platform, you can open port 3000 at FIREWALL RULES in VPC network.
It works for me.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwk2E.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j8Cg.png]