# nodejs This site can’t be reached centos7

Tags: node.js, centos7

I am new to node js and this is the first time I try to run node server on centos7 server.
This is the code in my file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


//setting
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);



app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('server on port ', app.get('port'));
});
```

For some reason I get **This site can’t be reached** error while trying to load http://*********:3000

I foloewd this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877965/this-site-can-t-be-reached-on-nodejs-express) but couldn't resolve the error.

I placed this string in the terminal `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT`

This is the site `iptables -L` output

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:hbci
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:origo-native

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
IN_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't opened the port in the firewall in the server.

what I did was set port 3000 as mpublic:

`[root@aaa ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent`

than I reloded the firewall:

`[root@aaa ~]# firewall-cmd --reload`

and that's all folks